# Org babel code blocks cannot be called from a org table

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, org-mode, org-babel

I am having trouble calling my babel code blocks from tables using
`sbe`. Here are some minimal examples that don't work for me:

```
|   |    in: | in:    | out:     | out:     | out:      |
| ! | number | string | elispStr | elispNum | pythonStr |
|---+--------+--------+----------+----------+-----------|
| # |      5 | fd     | #ERROR   | #ERROR   | #ERROR    |
| # |      7 | fadsf  | #ERROR   | #ERROR   | #ERROR    |
#+TBLFM: $4='(sbe elispStrBlock (foo $string))::$5='(sbe elispNumBlock (a $number));N::$6='(sbe pythonStrBlock (foo $string))

#+name elispNumBlock
#+header: :var a=4
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value
(message (number-to-string a))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 4

#+name elispStrBlock
#+header: :var a="testing"
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value 
(message a)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: testing

#+name pythonStrBlock
#+header: :var foo="testing"
#+begin_src python :results output
print foo
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: testing
```

The code blocks work when I evaluate them with `C-c C-c` with the
point in the block (hence the `#+RESULTS` output shown above).

I have looked at the mailing lists (for [example](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-10/msg00656.html)) and have seen
that some people can output babel errors to an `*Org Babel Error
Output*` buffer, I guess this would help debugging but I couldn't see
where to turn this on (`toggle-debug-on-error` didn't work)

I am using org-version: 8.2.3c.  I have also tried the above in a
fresh emacs with the `-q` option to ignore my config on startup.  I
have made sure that python is enabled for evaluation:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((emacs-lisp . t) (python . t)))
```

Comment: The `*Org Babel Error Output*` buffer opens if the process exists with an exit code ≠ 0. The `stderr`-output goes there. This is quite hard-coded into `org-babel-eval-error-notify` called at end of `org-babel-eval`.

Comment: You can debug into the evaluation by instrumenting `org-table-eval-formula` and `sbe` for debugging, setting a break point at `(eval (eval (read form)))` and then stepping into until you arrive within `sbe`. Things I already noticed: (1) Numeric arguments do not really work because of `org-no-properties` in `sbe`.  My org-version is: 8.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging revealed: a colon is missing in

`#+name elispNumBlock`

It must be:

`#+name: elispNumBlock`

The following advice delivers error messages of `sbe` to the message buffer:

```
(defadvice sbe (around get-err-msg activate)
  "Issue messages at errors."
  (condition-case err
      (progn
    ad-do-it)
    ((error debug)
     (message "Error in sbe: %S" err)
     (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))
```

Without it error messages are just translated into the table cell content `#ERROR`. Not so informative.

As I already commented: The `N` output format does not really work as expected. The resulting strings are substituted into the command call. So you need additional quoting for strings.

For me, the following is working:

```
|   |    in: | in:     | out:     |     out: | out:      |
| ! | number | string  | elispStr | elispNum | pythonStr |
|---+--------+---------+----------+----------+-----------|
| # |      5 | "fd"    | fd       |        5 | fd        |
| # |      7 | "fadsf" | fadsf    |        7 | fadsf     |
#+TBLFM: $4='(sbe elispStrBlock (foo $string))::$5='(sbe elispNumBlock (a $number))::$6='(sbe pythonStrBlock (foo $string))

#+name: elispNumBlock
#+header: :var a=4
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value
(message (number-to-string a))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 4

#+name: elispStrBlock
#+header: :var foo="testing"
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results value 
(message foo)
#+end_src


#+name: pythonStrBlock
#+header: :var foo="testing"
#+begin_src python :results output
print foo
#+end_src
```

EDIT: About the cell references "$2". The following works for me:

```
| ! | arg | res |
|---+-----+-----|
| # |   1 |   2 |
| # |   2 |   3 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(sbe myColFm (el $2))

#+name: myColFm
#+header: :var el=1
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (1+ el)
#+end_src
```

EDIT: With the additional advice

```
(defadvice sbe (before escape-args activate)
  "Apply prin1 to argument values."
  (mapc '(lambda (var) (setcdr var (list (prin1-to-string (cadr var))))) variables))
```

the command `sbe` works as one would expect:

```
| ! | arg | res |   |
|---+-----+-----+---|
| # |   1 |   3 | 5 |
| # |   2 |   4 | 6 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(sbe myStr (el $2))::$4='(sbe myColFm (el $2));N

#+name: myStr
#+header: :var el="1"
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (+ 2 (string-to-number el))
#+end_src

#+name: myColFm
#+header: :var el=1
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (+ 4 el)
#+end_src
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much your answer worked. I wasn't able to see how your defadvice helps though? When I evaluated it I didn't see a difference when I evaluated formulas with errors. Also, shouldn't it be possible to pass strings using "$1" provided the ;L is appended to the end of the formula?

Comment: Answer to 1st question: The `defadvice` only works for `sbe`-calls. The message goes into the `*Messages*` buffer. You can guess what you have to expect from the `message`-call in the advice. Answer to 2nd question: The received argument string is used to create the command call string. Thus, all arguments to a source block call must be strings (as far as I read from the source code). This is the reason why `; N` did not work. I do not know whether "$1" should work or not.

Comment: Thanks, I see the info in the `*Messages*` buffer like you said, and it helped me debug another issue I had. I think "$1" should work, well that's the impression I get from the manual page 'Emacs Lisp forms as formulas' here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp I'll see I get the time to follow it up later. Thanks

Comment: I have also edited the advice. It now gives reasonable output with debug on error.

Comment: I have added a rather interesting second advice `escape-args` for `sbe`. It gives `sbe` the behavior expected by you. Since it changes the behavior of `sbe` I do not know whether it breaks something in `org`.

Comment: I copied the last code block precisely to try and get a working starting point for something, and I just get `| # |   1 | #ERROR | #ERROR |`  ... To keep looing.